# TransactionTemplate vs JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring

The Spring framework provides two means of programmatic transaction management:

1. Using the `TransactionTemplate`.
2. Using a `PlatformTransactionManager` implementation directly.

The above is described here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/transaction.html

The Spring site  hasnot mentioned `JdbcTemplate` here. As per my understanding `JdbcTemplate` also manages the transaction internally and this is all done in programme too.

So what's the basic difference between `TransactionTemplate` and `JdbcTemplate`?

Comment: You need to stop reading ancient versions of the Spring manual. 2.0.x is several years old.

Comment: what is the  latest version i should look in to?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`JdbcTemplate` is not a transaction manager. It's merely a helper class for native JDBC operations:

> This is the central class in the JDBC core package. It simplifies the use of JDBC and helps to avoid common errors. It executes core JDBC workflow, leaving application code to provide SQL and extract results. This class executes SQL queries or updates, initiating iteration over ResultSets and catching JDBC exceptions and translating them to the generic, more informative exception hierarchy defined in the org.springframework.dao package.

`TransactionTemplate` by the way is also not a transaction manager, it's a

> Template class that simplifies programmatic transaction demarcation and transaction exception handling.

The `PlatformTransactionManager` (and other subclasses of `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager`) **is a transaction manager**, as in it

- determines if there is an existing transaction;
- applies the appropriate propagation behavior;
- suspends and resumes transactions if necessary;
- checks the rollback-only flag on commit;
- applies the appropriate modification on rollback (actual rollback or setting rollback-only);
- triggers registered synchronization callbacks (if transaction synchronization is active).

So this class is responsible for the actual transaction handling, as opposed to the `TransactionTemplate`, which is to be used if you instead of declarative transaction handling you want to implement it programmetically. (see [this](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2007/03/spring-jdbctemplate-and-transactions.html) blog, though quite outdated, you will see the difference between declarative and manual)

Quotes from [Spring 3 Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/).

Note: Throughout the Spring Framework you will find other *Template classes as well: HibernateTemplate, JmsTemplate etc. They all follow the same pattern: template classes which radically reduce the amount of code you need to write, because all the so-called boilerplate code will be handled by them. Example (from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-jdbcdaosupport-examples/)):

Without `JdbcTemplate`:

```
private DataSource dataSource;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public void insert(Customer customer){

    String sql = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER " +
            "(CUST_ID, NAME, AGE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, customer.getCustId());
        ps.setString(2, customer.getName());
        ps.setInt(3, customer.getAge());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

And with `JdbcTemplate`:

```
private DataSource dataSource;
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public void insert(Customer customer){

    String sql = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER " +
        "(CUST_ID, NAME, AGE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] { customer.getCustId(),
        customer.getName(),customer.getAge()  
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks abalogh. If we dont use transactionManager and Transaction template with Jdbc template, transaction will be commited 
in each method. Right? But if we use transactionManager and Transaction template with Jdbc template with 
PROPAGATION_REQUIRED  then trnsaction will be commited when it is exiting the main calling method.Is that
correct?